# WPF: StackPanel with FirstChildFill?

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, fill

I want a logical and simple way of producing a layout with one control set to fill and the rest to dock. I could use:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
  <Button Content="3" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
  <Button Content="2" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
  <Button Content="1" />
</DockPanel>
```

But its not very intuitive to use. I could also do it like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Button Content="1" Grid.Row="0" />
  <Button Content="2" Grid.Row="1" />
  <Button Content="3" Grid.Row="2" />
</Grid>
```

But its also quite alot of xaml. What I really want is something like this:

```
<StackPanel Fill="None|First|Last">
  <Button Content="1" />
  <Button Content="2" />
  <Button Content="3" />
</StackPanel>
```

How could this be achieved while not having to reverse the items as with DockPanel and not using a fixed number of rows and attached properties as with Grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always write your own panel with different docking rules.   You could use the standard DockPanel implementation (available in the framework source - it doesn't look very complicated) and create something similar with rules you prefer.   You might even be able to create a class which derives from DockPanel and overrides ArrangeOverride.

But personally I would just use the dock panel, which does exactly what you want except that you don't like its rules about which member gets to be the fill.

IME grid has a horrible maintenance problem if you insert/delete rows, in that you find yourself endlessly adjusting row numbers - DockPanel is much easier in that regard.

Update:

Here you go, I've denied you the pleasure of doing this yourself - this is just cut-down/reversed version of the framework source:

```
public class BottomDockingPanel : DockPanel
{
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        UIElementCollection children = InternalChildren;
        int totalChildrenCount = children.Count;

        double accumulatedBottom = 0;

        for (int i = totalChildrenCount-1; i >=0 ; --i)
        {
            UIElement child = children[i];
            if (child == null) { continue; }

            Size childDesiredSize = child.DesiredSize;
            Rect rcChild = new Rect(
                0,
                0,
                Math.Max(0.0, arrangeSize.Width - (0 + (double)0)),
                Math.Max(0.0, arrangeSize.Height - (0 + accumulatedBottom)));

            if (i > 0)
            {
                accumulatedBottom += childDesiredSize.Height;
                rcChild.Y = Math.Max(0.0, arrangeSize.Height - accumulatedBottom);
                rcChild.Height = childDesiredSize.Height;
            }

            child.Arrange(rcChild);
        }
        return (arrangeSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a DockPanel with a StackPanel inside it. The "main" content would be shown last instead of first, but at least the bottom content would be shown in a logical order in your XAML. If you're willing to have the filled content be last, this would be the simplest way to go.

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
  <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <Button Content="Bottom 1" />
    <Button Content="Bottom 2" />
    <Button Content="Bottom 3" />
  </StackPanel>
  <Button Content="Main" />
</DockPanel>
```

Or, if you want it all (including the filled content) to show up in the XAML in the same order it shows up on the screen, you could use a Grid with two rows and a StackPanel in the second row. As you pointed out, grids entail a fair bit of XAML, but the nested StackPanel would save you from having to add a RowDefinition and Grid.Row for each new item.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Main" />
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <Button Content="Bottom 1" />
    <Button Content="Bottom 2" />
    <Button Content="Bottom 3" />
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The problem with my specific case is that I want to produce this layout with a template on a ItemsContainer and I assume there is no way of splitting the itemspresenter in a "Main" and "the rest"-enumerable. If it was possible I could do like this...

Comment: You could always have your ViewModel expose two properties: one for the first child (that you want to fill the space), and one for the remaining items. Then you could use a ContentControl for the first one, and an ItemsControl for the rest. Not totally elegant, but quite a bit simpler than writing your own Panel.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such panel in WPF that would support this out of the box. If you want this particular behavior, you could create your own panel, but I would NOT advise you to do so, because it is pretty custom and needed not that often (what if want a panel that would have a behavior like MiddleChildFill? Would create your own panel for that case too?).

Usually this kind of layout is achieved using `Grid` (as you mentioned). Yes, this is true that `Grid` has a very verbose syntax (you could simplify it using a helper like [this](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/12/a-simplified-grid-markup-for-silverlight-and-wpf/)), but it gives you the most flexibility. And at the end of the day, this is what counts.

Comment: I use this layout model quite often accually. A StackPanel with an option to fill last or first child would be very useful I think.

Comment: @Andreas Zita - This is your choice, I'm just sharing my experience :)